# Trying to access array offset on value of type null in laravel 5.8 and and upgrade php 7.4

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

everything works fine before upgrade but since I upgraded to php 7.4 , my web application return an error like

> **Trying to access array offset on value of type null**

Here is my code

```
    @if(isset($data)) 
    @if(isset($data['panel']) && ($data['panel'] !==null)) // possible problem
    @dd($data); // since i put dd here maybe i manage to figure the line code on the line above 
    @php if(isset($data['customer'])) { $customerList = implode(',', $data['customer']); } @endphp
    @php if(isset($data['status'])) { $statusList = implode(',', $data['status']); } @endphp
        <input type="hidden" name="panelSort" value="@if(isset($data['panel'])){{ $data['panel']  }}@endif" />
        <input type="hidden" name="idleRange" value="@if(isset($data['idleRange'])){{ $data['idleRange']  }}@endif" />
        <input type="hidden" name="statusSort" value="@if(isset($statusList)){{ $statusList }}@endif" />
        <input type="hidden" name="customerDbSort" value="@if(isset($customerList)){{ $customerList  }}@endif" />
        <input type="hidden" name="severityDbSort" value="@if(isset($data['severity'])){{ $data['severity']  }}@endif" />
        <input type="hidden" name="prDbSort" value="@if(isset($data['pr'])){{ $data['pr']  }}@endif" />
        <input type="hidden" name="catDbSort" value="@if(isset($data['category'])){{ $data['category']  }}@endif" />

@endif
@endif
```

The possible problem is **$data[panel]** which is i mark as comment on the code

What i have tried is i change php version on composer.json and run command

> composer update

Comment: Can't you replace "    @if(isset($data['panel']) && ($data['panel'] !==null))" with   "  @if(isset($data['panel']))" ?

Comment: sorry but I had already try this before but still same

Comment: and you're sure that it's the problematic line?

Comment: can I see your query for $data variable.

Comment: Please share more details by editing your question. Also, please explain why this is tagged with Composer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try below solution.

```php
@php
    $customerlist = (isset($data['customer']))? implode(',', $data['customer']):''
    $statusList = (isset($data['status']))? implode(',', $data['status']):''
@endphp
<input type="hidden" name="panelSort" value="{{ $data['panel'] or ''  }}" />
<input type="hidden" name="idleRange" value="{{ $data['idleRange'] or ''  }}" />
<input type="hidden" name="statusSort" value="{{ $statusList }}" />
<input type="hidden" name="customerDbSort" value="{{ $customerList  }}" />
<input type="hidden" name="severityDbSort" value="{{ $data['severity'] or '' }}" />
<input type="hidden" name="prDbSort" value="{{ $data['pr'] or '' }}" />
<input type="hidden" name="catDbSort" value="{{ $data['category'] or '' }}" />
```

Check whether installed Laravel version support `or` blade directive. If this `or` doesn't support you can use null coalesce operator i.e. `??`.

Refer [this](https://www.brainbell.com/php/null-coalescing-operator.html)